# Android Studio Arctic Fox 2 cannot launch on Linux

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio Arctic Fox 2 fails to start on Linux. Here's the errors when run from terminal:

```
Start Failed: Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace

-----
JRE 11.0.8+0-b944-P17168821 amd64 by N/A
/home/johndoe/.local/android-studio-preview/android-studio/jre

Also, a UI exception occurred on an attempt to show the above message:

Also, a UI exception occurred on an attempt to show the above message:
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1"

2020-12-07 01:01:59,866 [  17998]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Metaspace 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
2020-12-07 01:01:59,866 [  17998]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Canary 2  Build #AI-202.7319.50.2031.7006259 
2020-12-07 01:01:59,866 [  17998]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 11.0.8; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: N/A 
2020-12-07 01:01:59,867 [  17999]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Linux 

Start Failed: Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace

-----
JRE 11.0.8+0-b944-P17168821 amd64 by N/A
/home/johndoe/.local/android-studio-preview/android-studio/jre

Also, a UI exception occurred on an attempt to show the above message:
2020-12-07 01:02:00,211 [  18343]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Metaspace 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
2020-12-07 01:02:00,212 [  18344]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Canary 2  Build #AI-202.7319.50.2031.7006259 
2020-12-07 01:02:00,296 [  18428]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Metaspace 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
2020-12-07 01:02:00,296 [  18428]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 11.0.8; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: N/A 
2020-12-07 01:02:00,297 [  18429]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Canary 2  Build #AI-202.7319.50.2031.7006259 
2020-12-07 01:02:00,297 [  18429]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Linux 
2020-12-07 01:02:00,297 [  18429]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 11.0.8; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: N/A 

Start Failed: Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace

-----
JRE 11.0.8+0-b944-P17168821 amd64 by N/A
/home/johndoe/.local/android-studio-preview/android-studio/jre2020-12-07 01:02:00,297 [  18429]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Linux 


Start Failed: Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace

-----
JRE 11.0.8+0-b944-P17168821 amd64 by N/A
/home/johndoe/.local/android-studio-preview/android-studio/jre

Also, a UI exception occurred on an attempt to show the above message:

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1"

Also, a UI exception occurred on an attempt to show the above message:
2020-12-07 01:02:00,948 [  19080]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Metaspace 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
2020-12-07 01:02:00,948 [  19080]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Canary 2  Build #AI-202.7319.50.2031.7006259 
2020-12-07 01:02:00,948 [  19080]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 11.0.8; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: N/A 
2020-12-07 01:02:00,948 [  19080]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Linux 

Start Failed: Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace

-----
JRE 11.0.8+0-b944-P17168821 amd64 by N/A
/home/johndoe/.local/android-studio-preview/android-studio/jre

Also, a UI exception occurred on an attempt to show the above message:
2020-12-07 01:02:01,271 [  19403]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Metaspace 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
2020-12-07 01:02:01,271 [  19403]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Canary 2  Build #AI-202.7319.50.2031.7006259 
2020-12-07 01:02:01,271 [  19403]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 11.0.8; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: N/A 
2020-12-07 01:02:01,369 [  19501]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Linux 

Start Failed: Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace

-----
JRE 11.0.8+0-b944-P17168821 amd64 by N/A
/home/johndoe/.local/android-studio-preview/android-studio/jre2020-12-07 01:02:01,369 [  19501]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Metaspace 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
2020-12-07 01:02:01,370 [  19502]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Canary 2  Build #AI-202.7319.50.2031.7006259 
2020-12-07 01:02:01,370 [  19502]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 11.0.8; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: N/A 
2020-12-07 01:02:01,370 [  19502]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Linux 


Start Failed: Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace

-----
JRE 11.0.8+0-b944-P17168821 amd64 by N/A
/home/johndoe/.local/android-studio-preview/android-studio/jre

Also, a UI exception occurred on an attempt to show the above message:

Also, a UI exception occurred on an attempt to show the above message:
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1"

2020-12-07 01:02:02,031 [  20163]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Metaspace 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
2020-12-07 01:02:02,031 [  20163]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Canary 2  Build #AI-202.7319.50.2031.7006259 
2020-12-07 01:02:02,031 [  20163]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 11.0.8; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: N/A 
2020-12-07 01:02:02,031 [  20163]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Linux 

Start Failed: Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace

-----
JRE 11.0.8+0-b944-P17168821 amd64 by N/A
/home/johndoe/.local/android-studio-preview/android-studio/jre

Also, a UI exception occurred on an attempt to show the above message:
2020-12-07 01:02:02,372 [  20504]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Metaspace 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
2020-12-07 01:02:02,372 [  20504]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Canary 2  Build #AI-202.7319.50.2031.7006259 
2020-12-07 01:02:02,372 [  20504]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 11.0.8; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: N/A 
2020-12-07 01:02:02,372 [  20504]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Linux 

Start Failed: Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace

-----
JRE 11.0.8+0-b944-P17168821 amd64 by N/A
/home/johndoe/.local/android-studio-preview/android-studio/jre2020-12-07 01:02:02,459 [  20591]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Metaspace 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
2020-12-07 01:02:02,459 [  20591]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Canary 2  Build #AI-202.7319.50.2031.7006259 

2020-12-07 01:02:02,459 [  20591]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 11.0.8; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: N/A 
2020-12-07 01:02:02,460 [  20592]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Linux 

Start Failed: Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace

-----
JRE 11.0.8+0-b944-P17168821 amd64 by N/A
/home/johndoe/.local/android-studio-preview/android-studio/jre

Also, a UI exception occurred on an attempt to show the above message:

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1"

Also, a UI exception occurred on an attempt to show the above message:
2020-12-07 01:02:03,110 [  21242]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Metaspace 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
2020-12-07 01:02:03,110 [  21242]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Canary 2  Build #AI-202.7319.50.2031.7006259 
2020-12-07 01:02:03,110 [  21242]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 11.0.8; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: N/A 
2020-12-07 01:02:03,110 [  21242]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Linux 

Start Failed: Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace

-----
JRE 11.0.8+0-b944-P17168821 amd64 by N/A
/home/johndoe/.local/android-studio-preview/android-studio/jre

Also, a UI exception occurred on an attempt to show the above message:
2020-12-07 01:02:03,465 [  21597]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Metaspace 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
2020-12-07 01:02:03,465 [  21597]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Canary 2  Build #AI-202.7319.50.2031.7006259 
2020-12-07 01:02:03,465 [  21597]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 11.0.8; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: N/A 
2020-12-07 01:02:03,465 [  21597]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Linux 

Start Failed: Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace

-----
JRE 11.0.8+0-b944-P17168821 amd64 by N/A
/home/johndoe/.local/android-studio-preview/android-studio/jre

Also, a UI exception occurred on an attempt to show the above message:

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1"
./studio.sh: line 195: 12635 Killed                  "$JAVA_BIN" -classpath "$CLASSPATH" ${VM_OPTIONS} "-XX:ErrorFile=$HOME/java_error_in_STUDIO_%p.log" "-XX:HeapDumpPath=$HOME/java_error_in_STUDIO.hprof" -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudioPreview2020.3 "-Djb.vmOptionsFile=$VM_OPTIONS_FILES" ${IDE_PROPERTIES_PROPERTY} -Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio -Didea.jre.check=true com.intellij.idea.Main "$@"
```

I tried changing studio.vmoptions as follows, but it didn't help (worth to mention that it failed just after a fresh install):

```
-server
-Xms128m

-Xmx2048m

-XX:MaxPermSize=350m

-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=96m

-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-XX:CICompilerCount=2
-Dsun.io.useCanonPrefixCache=false
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off
-Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=
-Didea.vendor.name=Google
-XX:MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=10000
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-ea
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
-Dsun.java2d.renderer=sun.java2d.marlin.MarlinRenderingEngine
-Dsun.tools.attach.tmp.only=true
-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70
```

OS Info:

Fedora 32 on Intel

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues#studio-config-directories) on Android Studio's known issues, this might happen after an upgrade. The solution is to remove configuration of previous Android Studio versions. On Linux, these directories are located at ~/.config/Google/AndroidStudioXX where XX stands for version. You can remove all of them if there are multiple, and then run Android Studio again. This will likely solve any misconfiguration issues like that mentioned in the question.